# showing set of divs based on checkbox selection

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to find JQ alternative for this script [link to see exampe](http://jsfiddle.net/makypl/aKhQK/) the problem is that I want to use classes instead of IDs, and single div can have more then 1 class, so can be displayed after checking checkbox1 or checkbox2 or both of them. Any idea how to make it works ?

```
function toggle(matchingAttribute) {
    // optain all div elements in the page
    var divArray = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
      for(i=divArray.length-1; i>=0; i--) {  // for each div
      if(divArray[i].id.match("_"+matchingAttribute+"_")) {
        if(divArray[i].style.display != 'none') {
          divArray[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
          divArray[i].style.display = '';
        }
      }
    }
  }  // end function toggle()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.chk').click(function(){
    var className = $(this).attr('data-class');
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $('.'+className+'').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('.'+className+'').hide();
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aKhQK/8/)

Comment: I did not asked the question ;). I've just tried to code a solution as well

Comment: Don't use "rel", use data attributes instead they are more syntactically correct. "rel" are only supposed to be used on anchor tags to represent the relationship between the current document and linked document.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the examples is based off of three different parameters. The Location, the Type, and the Cost

You can have your checkbox setup with a data-attribute and then have all your divs setup with classes to respectivly turn them on and off.

See the example below.

http://jsfiddle.net/YH5wA/1/

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Selector").click(function(){
        var Attribute = $(this).data("attribute");
        if($(this).prop('checked'))
        {
            $(".Options div." + Attribute).show();
        }
        else
        {
            $(".Options div." + Attribute).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
    Location:
    <br />
    <input class="Selector" type="checkbox" checked data-attribute="nj"> NJ
    <input class="Selector" type="checkbox" checked data-attribute="ny"> NY
    <input class="Selector" type="checkbox" checked data-attribute="ct"> CT
    <br />
    Value:
    <br />
    <input class="Selector" type="checkbox" checked data-attribute="cheap"> Cheap
    <input class="Selector" type="checkbox" checked data-attribute="moderate"> Moderate
    <input class="Selector" type="checkbox" checked data-attribute="expensive"> Expensive
    <br />
    Type:
    <br />
    <input class="Selector" type="checkbox" checked data-attribute="burgers"> Burgers
    <input class="Selector" type="checkbox" checked data-attribute="pizza"> Pizza
    <input class="Selector" type="checkbox" checked data-attribute="sandwiches"> Sandwiches
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="Options">
        <div class="nj cheap burgers">NJ Place [Cheap Burger]</div>
        <div class="nj moderate burgers">NJ Place [Moderate Burgers]</div>
        <div class="nj expensive burgers">NJ Place [Expensive Burgers]</div>
        <div class="nj cheap pizza">NJ Place [Cheap Pizza]</div>
        <div class="nj moderate pizza">NJ Place [Moderate Pizza]</div>
        <div class="nj expensive pizza">NJ Place [Expensive Pizza]</div>
        <div class="nj cheap sandwiches">NJ Place [Cheap Sandwitches]</div>
        <div class="nj moderate sandwiches">NJ Place [Moderate Sandwitches]</div>
        <div class="nj expensive sandwiches">NJ Place [Expensive Sandwitches]</div>
        <div class="ny cheap burgers">NY Place [Cheap Burger]</div>
        <div class="ny moderate burgers">NY Place [Moderate Burgers]</div>
        <div class="ny expensive burgers">NY Place [Expensive Burgers]</div>
        <div class="ny cheap pizza">NY Place [Cheap Pizza]</div>
        <div class="ny moderate pizza">NY Place [Moderate Pizza]</div>
        <div class="ny expensive pizza">NY Place [Expensive Pizza]</div>
        <div class="ny cheap sandwiches">NY Place [Cheap Sandwitches]</div>
        <div class="ny moderate sandwiches">NY Place [Moderate Sandwitches]</div>
        <div class="ny expensive sandwiches">NY Place [Expensive Sandwitches]</div>
        <div class="ct cheap burgers">CT Place [Cheap Burger]</div>
        <div class="ct moderate burgers">CT Place [Moderate Burgers]</div>
        <div class="ct expensive burgers">CT Place [Expensive Burgers]</div>
        <div class="ct cheap pizza">CT Place [Cheap Pizza]</div>
        <div class="ct moderate pizza">CT Place [Moderate Pizza]</div>
        <div class="ct expensive pizza">CT Place [Expensive Pizza]</div>
        <div class="ct cheap sandwiches">CT Place [Cheap Sandwitches]</div>
        <div class="ct moderate sandwiches">CT Place [Moderate Sandwitches]</div>
        <div class="ct expensive sandwiches">CT Place [Expensive Sandwitches]</div>
    </div>
```